# Change default URL or path for whole application?

Tags: php, configuration, laravel-5, uri, relative-path

On my local development I face the issue that my applicaton uses relative path, to the domain, e.g. `/css/style.css`.

This works generally good, as I can configure virutal hosts on my develop machine, e.g. `localhost.foo`, so that the relative path is resolved to `localhost.foo/css/style.css`.

In my current situation, I cannot edit the hosts file to setup a development domain, so that the relative path to the domain does not work anymore. My develop url looks like `localhost/projectfoo/public`.

So that the app works, it should reference to `localhost/projectfoo/public/css/style.css`. Based on the relative path in the code it now reference to `locahost/css/style.css`, and there it will - obviously - not find the requested files.

Is there a way to configure laravel, to use at one case `localhost/projectfoo/public` as URL and on the other case the standard?

Comment: If it is only for css and script files, you might want to use `<base href="http://example.com">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has a helper function `asset` which generates a full URL for a relative path, based on your config `app.url` value.

For example, if `app.url` is `http://localhost`:

In your view put `{{ asset("css/style.css") }}` and Laravel will convert this to `http://localhost/css/style.css`

So in your case all you need to do is change `app.url` to `http://localhost/public` and then start using that `asset` method in your views instead of the relative path.

Better yet, add a new environment variable to your `.env` file (make sure to put it in `.env.example` as well) called `APP_URL`, e.g.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Then in `config/app.php` set it to:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL'),
```

That way you only have to set it once per environment

Comment: On my local machine it was enough to change all path to `{{asset('/path/to/foo')` and now it works. Have to check how it is on the other environements.

Comment: works as well on the other environment. So currentlz I did not have to change the `url` in `config/app.php`. For me it works to just use `asset()` in blade.

Comment: @jerik great to hear that

Answer (score 2):

You can always add a new entry in your config files, lets say in the `config/app.php`

```
// this is the one that comes with laravel
'url' => 'http://localhost',

// this is the one that you can define
'url_public' => 'http://localhost/something_else/public'
```

and then use it in your view like:

```
<link href="{{ config('app.url_public') }}/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Why would they add another config value instead of just changing `url`? It comes with Laravel because it's intended to be changed

Comment: Of course it's intended to be changed. The way I understood the last paragraph of the question is that he wanted to have two, for different situations. So as a general approach, you can use the one that comes with Laravel (with or without changing it) plus one that you can define on your own. Whether that's how he must work given his constraints in the environment, we don't (or at least I) don't know.

Comment: ok that makes sense. I understood the 2 situations to be 2 separate environments though. In that case I think it makes more sense to add url to the `.env` file and adjust it based on the environment.